# Text fields issue with Ext form FieldContainer

Tags: layout, width, textfield, extjs5

I am trying to create text fields horizontally. However, neither fields width nor positions are as expected. In specific, area2 fieldlabel appears on previous text field. 
Below I attempt to add 7 text fields but on run there is only 6 text fields in the layout.

area1  :|__ | |__ | |__ | |__ | area2: |__| area3 :|_______________________________|

here is my source code :

```
{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        border:true,
                        bodyPadding:5,
                        width :861,
                        layout:'column',
                        items:[ {
                                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel  : 'area1',
                                    width       : 100,

                                 },
                                 {
                                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                                    width       :50,
                                },{
                                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                                    width       :50,
                                },{
                                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                                    width       :50,
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                                    width       :50,
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel  :'area2',
                                    width       :100,
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype       : 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel  :' area3',
                                    width       :400
                                }

                        ]   
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout you are after can be better achieved by:

1. using container (instead of panel that is too heavy) with `hbox` layout that is better configurable than column layout
2. using field container: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer

Comment: Further on that - the column layout is why you're only seeing six fields; the seventh field will be wrapped to the next row.

The column layout won't make your container grow or scroll - if it's not big enough, subsequent columns wrap around.

(You could test that by increasing the width of the container from 861 - if it's off by as little as 1 pixel, you get the wrapping effect)

Comment: Thank you for your answer i try with fieldcontainer,so its what i am looking.

And i try increase the width before your reply and it is not working. one of textfield  does not seem. if i create six fields,five fields appear. i don't understand.

And one more question, can i do a form in one panel with have horizontally and vertically textfiels at the same time ?

Comment: The best would be if you could post a showcase of what you have now at https://fiddle.sencha.com And yes, you can have any layout in the form.